# how to convert values in a table in nearst integer values removing the decimal points?

Tags: bash

I have a file say `file.tsv` which has several columns and looks like:

```
# Gene Family   xyz136  xyz140  xyz145  xyz147  xyz148
UNMAPPED    7650721.04472   4253028.928704  8415910.028496  7453466.3835    3282779.545448
UNGROUPED   4148127.07896   3999040.089552  4423800.370656  6066650.96145   4460845.331384
UNGROUPED|g__Absiella.s__Absiella_dolichum  0   0   8548.5181548    0   0
UNGROUPED|g__Acidaminococcus.s__Acidaminococcus_fermentans  0   0   0   0   0
UNGROUPED|g__Acidaminococcus.s__Acidaminococcus_intestini   0   0   0   0   0
UNGROUPED|g__Acidaminococcus.s__Acidaminococcus_intestini_CAG_325   0   0   0   0   0
```

How can I convert all the numerical values present in this table to convert to nearest integer by removing the decimal points?

I want it to look like this table:

```
# Gene Family   xyz136  xyz140  xyz145  xyz147  xyz148
UNMAPPED    7650721 4253029 8415910 7453466 3282780
UNGROUPED   4148127 3999040 4423800 6066651 4460845
UNGROUPED|g__Absiella.s__Absiella_dolichum  0   0   8549    0   0
UNGROUPED|g__Acidaminococcus.s__Acidaminococcus_fermentans  0   0   0   0   0
UNGROUPED|g__Acidaminococcus.s__Acidaminococcus_intestini   0   0   0   0   0
UNGROUPED|g__Acidaminococcus.s__Acidaminococcus_intestini_CAG_325   0   0   0   0   0
```

NOTE: Althoug it is a `.tsv` file it is not looking like a table. I don't know which formatting tool should I use for that.

Thanks,
dc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the `numfmt` utility, from GNU Coreutils:

```
numfmt --delimiter=$'\t' --header --format='%.0f' --field=2- <file.tsv
```

Alternatively, something like this in awk:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR>1 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=int($i+0.5)} 1' file.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver. I have used `awk` and it works!